# Managing and searching through millions of integers/coordinates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, rgb

I have an array of RGB value integers/whole numbers, ranging from 0 to 255. Eight Different lists.

For example one list has 8,349,042 values in it. OR 2,783,014 RGB sets of three.

The core objective is the user selects a pixel in an image.
That pixel's (R,G,B) value is grabbed and searched for within these lists. It exists in one of these lists, as all the lists together contain all the possible RGB combinations (16,777,216)

I'm trying to figure out what's the best way to store and search through these values.

again: these values don't change, they are hard coded lists(see Bullet Point below), with a known range.
The search query would be at minimum 3 times every event which would be every 10-30 seconds or so if the user was spamming.
OR Best case scenario, if the storage and search technique is fast enough I would like to: run the search on every pixel in an image (of maybe 800 x 600 or smaller resolutions) to have more data to play with. If I run into any memory limitations, I plan to work with it and use it as restrictions for my game design.

I used Javascript to generate these lists, going through and assigning each value based on how close it was to a base color.

[maybe unimportant how I made these lists]

- I first assigned black and white RGB lists based on hard numeric limitations, then the rest of the RGB values were looped through and assigned to their closest base colors, red, yellow, cyan, green, blue and magenta. If there was a tie in distance I gave it to currently shortest list to try to keep it somewhat balanced. I may try to optimize this later and generate a new list, but not during runtime, just raw data.

I saved the results in hard text, and they are currently stored as a text that I can dump into large array.

At first I was trying to store the data as a JSON file along with my scripts. But I struggled to read the data and save it to an array. I ran into issues with using fetch and async and not being able to have the array where I needed it. Testing with console.log(arr) and getting undefined. I'm guessing because it wasn't loaded yet.

I can just paste it hard coded into the array but it's ginormous and I know there has to be a better way.

Also, hearing about differences in arrays vs sets vs objects
and different searching techniques within them.
Most of them seemed to be more tactful for multi variable arrays like name and age and location databases.

Since my data is all numeric I was thinking it could be a more bit/byte based approach?

I was reading some things on trees and hashs, bit crunching encryption?
Trees seemed nice for quicker searching as I could try to assign each branch of the tree to each R, G and B of the value, but I would also need to figure out how to convert my Giant single list of numbers into that, it also could be just the search type and that may depend on how I store the data.

I also struggled to understand the difference between front end and back end. I believe everything I've tried would be considered front end as I'm only testing my code in a browser.

I was pointed towards Node for backend but got lost in trying to get the console to run things.

I'm willing to give any of these things a try but I don't want to go down a path and find out it can't do what I want, or not optimally enough, like a server burden, or user burden with waiting too long or unable to do things because of user data security, requiring the user to do something more than just load the game, permissives wise.

SO I'm hoping someone can give me suggestions on what I should pursue so I can knuckle down and have a better focus on what I need to learn to be well versed and best tackle problem.

EDIT: Simplified question: In Javascript, I have an array of 2 million (x,y,z) numbers. What's the best way to search that array for a specific (x,y,z) value?
Would it be better to store the data in a different format than an array for constant searches?

Comment: What's the goal of this search? Looks like [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me.

Comment: To determine which pre-made list of RGB values the inputted RGB value is in.

Comment: You do not understand my question.

Comment: After you've matched the pixel to a list, what do you do with that information?  The question does seem very [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/320245): "you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y."

Comment: Assign a value to a new variable, in it's base form. I plan to use the information to make stats, or spawn a creature, it just triggers a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain I've understood the overall goal here but have a suggestion to consider if you are trying to assign a predetermined value to some (almost random as it is picked as a pixel colour from an image) rgb number set.

I assume the list/dictionary you have made allocates some value to each rgb number set and that it can be regenerated or reformatted if needed.

There are a maximum of 16,777,216 rgba values (256^3). Javascript arrays can have up to 2^32-2 (almost 4.3 billion) elements. Therefore the suggestion is to reformat your dictionary to be a 3-dimensional array where each dimension is indexed 0-255. The array can be declared and assigned as an array literal in a regular js script (text file) like `colourDictionary= [[[val0]..[val255]]..[[]..[]],...[[val0]..[val255]]..[[]..[]]];` and each value accessed arithmetically in constant time using the pixel values as `colourDictionary[r][g][b]`

To be useful without writing lines to cater for missing values, your gaps (you mention a list of 8,349,042, around half the available number combinations) could be filled with the values of nearest neighbours.

Apologies if I've missed the point.

Comment: (ah sorry the 8,349,042 is how many integers there are, since each rgb is 3 integers,  it has 2,783,014 possible RGB combinations in that list.)

so you're suggesting I convert my lists into 3 value dictionaries?

Looking into dictionaries I would need to assign a value to each RGB, Would I just loop through and a value to each RGB in it's list, since they will all be the same in that list?

It feels the same as an array, there would only be 8 different outputs from the search. 1 from each list. Unless dictionary has better optimized searching.

Comment: if your dictionary uses numerical  keys the array is a simpler structure to store and retrieve the same data with the same keys. My suggestion is just to build the 3-d array using the numeric indices as keys. I don't understand the 8 different outputs from the search so may be wildly off.

Comment: 8 lists. depending on which list the RGB value is in, outputs a data point that I can later use, such as var userColor = "Red"; I'll need to look up and understand dictionaries better